# Selecting Pandas data by column levels/ axis 1 multi-index

Tags: python, pandas, multi-index

Here is a piece of code that accomplishes part of what I'm trying to do:

```
selection=df.xs(('year2012','3quarter','A'),level=[0,1,2],axis=1)
```

How can I make a selection of multiple criteria in each level of axis 1?
The following seems to be the wrong way to accomplish this.

`selection=df.xs(( ['year2012','year2015'] , ['3quarter','4quarter'] , 'A'), level=[0,1,2], axis=1`)

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the example dataframe `df`

```
mux = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([
        ['year{}'.format(i) for i in range(2010, 2017)],
        ['{}quarter'.format(i) for i in range(1, 5)],
        list('ABCD')
    ])

df = pd.DataFrame([np.arange(len(mux))], columns=mux)

df
```

[image]

The way to do this is to use `pd.IndexSlice`

```
l1 = ['year2012','year2015']
l2 = ['3quarter','4quarter']
l3 = 'A'

df.loc[:, pd.IndexSlice[l1, l2, l3]]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your help!

This message came up as I applied the solution to my dataframe- _italic_KeyError: 'MultiIndex Slicing requires the index to be fully lexsorted tuple len_italic_
But it was because I missed the step where you sorted the index. Fixed it with this- `code`mydataframe.sort_index(axis=1, inplace=True)`code`